# span and anchor default height

Tags: css

Could you tell me why `<a>` has a different height of the span element?

Why `<a>` is vertical centered aligned and span is taking all the vertical available space?

http://jsfiddle.net/vpVEf/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are some issues with your code. First you have `font-size:3em` for `span` but not for `a`. Also you `float:right` the span but you don't `float:left` the `a` as a result the `span`'s content reach the right top side of parent `li`.

Solution: add `font-size:3em` for `li` and remove it from `span`. Add `float:left` for `a`. To clear the `float` add `overflow:hidden` for `li`. But because you use `outline` the black lines will not be visible. So change `outline` to `border:3px solid #000`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vpVEf/13/

Comment: Hi, I want my span bigger than the <a>. Is it possible?

Comment: @Ronaldo change the `font-size` of `span` and add a fixed `height` for the `li`

Answer (score 2):

It's because your list-item line-height is 70px. Span height is based on line height.

```
#MenuEventos li {
line-height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: And <a> element is not aligned with list-item? how can I keep <a> and <span> verticaly aligned?